# I cant run my rspec in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I cant really get going with my Rspec-gem :) Unfortunately. It seems like the Rspec-rails gem works differently now? Any idea?
This is my error Im getting:

```
testing_rspec/spec/models/transport_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Transport (NameError)
    from /Users/yoniPacheko/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1057:in `load'
```

My spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Transport do

end
```

This is my [file](https://github.com/yonipacheko/rspec_is_fucked/tree/master/spec)

Thanks for yr time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a newly-generated app, you should be using `require 'rails_helper'`, instead of requiring spec_helper.

`rspec-rails` 3 has split the two out so that `spec_helper` can be used for standalone Ruby code, and `rails_helper` (which includes spec_helper) can be used for testing code that relies on Rails.

Comment: Hi there! It doesn't work properly Im getting this: http://pastie.org/9436574 any idea? Im getting green at the end of this bunch of code...?

Comment: that's okay - those are just ruby warnings. You can disable those by removing `--warnings` from your `.rspec` file.

Comment: funny! are those warnings always there uhn?

Comment: they've always been there - it's just recent versions of rspec-rails that have enabled their display.